# Python use a list item to enable/disable a html check box

Tags: python, html, xml

Is it possible to enable or disable a HTML checkbox with a Python list. I am working on a project. I have used Python to parse an XML configuration file. I can populate the text areas of the HTML form using the list and binding. I want to do the same thing with drop down menus and checkboxes. I am not sure where to begin.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import config_settings
import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable(display=0,logdir="/var/www/cgi-bin/error-logs")





print("Content-Type: text/html\n\n")
print("")



    latitude = config_settings.settings[0]
    latHemi = config_settings.settings[1]
    longitude = config_settings.settings[2]
    longHemi = config_settings.settings[3]
    sensitivity = config_settings.settings[4]
    weight = config_settings.settings[5]
    if {weight} == config_settings.settings[5]:
        checked="{weight}"



    htmlFormat='''<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>EM2010 Sound Level Monitor - Setup</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="EM2010 User Interface">
        <meta name="author" content="Sonitus Systems">

    </head>

    <body>




               <form class="well form-inline" method="post" action="/cgi-bin/process_setup.cgi">

                  <!-- Location -->
                  <i class="icon-location-arrow icon-large"> <span class="setting">&nbsp;Location<span></span></i><br><br>
                  Latitude: <input type="text" name="latitude" class="input-small" value="{latitude}">&deg;



     <select name="latHemi">

      <option value="{latHemi}">N</option>
      <option>S</option></select>



       &nbsp;&nbsp;
       Longitude: <input type="text" name="longitude" class="input-small" value="{longitude}">&deg;

     <select name="longHemi">


         <option value="{longHemi}">W</option>
         <option>E</option></select>



    <hr/>
    <!-- Mic Sensitivity -->
    <i class="icon-microphone icon-large"> <span class="setting">&nbsp;Microphone<span></span></i><br><br>
    Sensitivity: <input type="text" name="sensitivity" class="input-small" value="{sensitivity}"> dB


     <hr/>
    <!-- Measurement Settings -->
    <i class="icon-edit icon-large"> <span class="setting">&nbsp;Measurement Settings<span></span></i><br><br>
    <h5>Weighting:</h5>

    <label class="checkbox inline control-label"><input name="Weight" value="aWeight" checked="{weight}" " type="checkbox">
    <span> A-Weight &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></label>


      <label class="checkbox inline control-label"><input name="Weight" value="cWeight" checked="" type="checkbox">



    <span> C-Weight</span></label>

    <br>
    <br>
    <h5>Optional Levels (L<sub>EQ</sub> is always recorded):</h5>




     <label class="checkbox inline control-label"><input name="L95" value="L95" checked="checked" type="checkbox">

       <!--<label class="checkbox inline control-label"><input name="L95" value="L95" type="checkbox">-->

    <span> L95  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></label>

     <label class="checkbox inline control-label"><input name="L90" value="L90" checked="checked" type="checkbox">

     <!--<label class="checkbox inline control-label"><input name="L90" value="L90" type="checkbox">-->

    <span> L90  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></label>

     <label class="checkbox inline control-label"><input name="L50" value="L50" checked="checked" type="checkbox">

     <!--<label class="checkbox inline control-label"><input name="L50" value="L50" type="checkbox">-->

    <span> L50  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></label>

     <label class="checkbox inline control-label"><input name="L10" value="L10" checked="checked" type="checkbox">

     <!--<label class="checkbox inline control-label"><input name="L10" value="L10" type="checkbox">-->

    <span> L10  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></label>

     <label class="checkbox inline control-label"><input name="L05" value="L05" checked="checked" type="checkbox">

     <!--<label class="checkbox inline control-label"><input name="L05" value="L05" type="checkbox">-->

    <span> L5  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></label>

     <label class="checkbox inline control-label"><input name="fmax" value="fmax" checked="checked" type="checkbox">

     <!--<label class="checkbox inline control-label"><input name="fmax" value="fmax" type="checkbox">-->

    <span> L<sub>MAX</sub></span></label>

    <br>
    <br>
    <h5>Averaging Period:</h5>





      <label class="radio inline control-label"><input name="epoc" value="1min" checked="checked" type="radio">

      <!--<label class="radio inline control-label"><input name="epoc" value="1min" type="radio">-->

    <span> 1 minute  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></label>

      <label class="radio inline control-label"><input name="epoc" value="5min" checked="checked" type="radio">

      <!--<label class="radio inline control-label"><input name="epoc" value="5min" type="radio">-->

     <span> 5 minutes  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></label>

      <label class="radio inline control-label"><input name="epoc" value="10min" checked="checked" type="radio">

     <!-- <label class="radio inline control-label"><input name="epoc" value="10min" type="radio">-->

    <span> 10 minutes  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></label>

      <label class="radio inline control-label"><input name="epoc" value="15min" checked="checked" type="radio">

      <!--<label class="radio inline control-label"><input name="epoc" value="15min" type="radio">-->

    <span> 15 minutes  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></label>

      <label class="radio inline control-label"><input name="epoc" value="30min" checked="checked" type="radio">



     <span> 30 minutes</span></label>



    <br>
    <br>
    <h5>Time Weighting (L<sub>MAX</sub>):</h5>





      <label class="radio inline control-label"><input name="fastaveraging" value="fastaveraging" checked="checked" type="radio">
      <span> 0.125s (Fast) &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></label>
      <label class="radio inline control-label"><input name="fastaveraging" value="empty" type="radio">
      <span> 1s (Slow)</span></label>

      <label class="radio inline control-label"><input name="fastaveraging" value="fastaveraging" type="radio">
      <span> 0.125s  (Fast)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></label>
      <label class="radio inline control-label"><input name="fastaveraging" value="empty" checked="checked" type="radio">
      <span> 1s (Slow)</span></label>

    <hr/>
    <!-- Reboot -->
     <i class="icon-refresh icon-large"> <span class="setting">&nbsp;Reboot Time<span></span></i><br><br>






      <label class="radio inline control-label"><input name="bootTime" value="midnight" checked="checked" type="radio">

      <!--<label class="radio inline control-label"><input name="bootTime" value="midnight" type="radio">-->

    <span >00:00hrs</span></label>


      <label class="radio inline control-label"><input name="bootTime" value="7am" checked="checked" type="radio">

     <!--<label class="radio inline control-label"><input name="bootTime" value="7am" type="radio">-->

    <span >07:00hrs</span></label>


      <label class="radio inline control-label"><input name="bootTime" value="7pm" checked="checked" type="radio">

      <!--<label class="radio inline control-label"><input name="bootTime" value="7pm" type="radio">-->

    <span >19:00hrs</span></label>


      <label class="radio inline control-label"><input name="bootTime" value="23pm" checked="checked" type="radio">
    else
      <!--<label class="radio inline control-label"><input name="bootTime" value="23pm" type="radio">-->

    <span >23:00hrs</span></label>




    <hr/>
    <!-- ISP -->
    <i class="icon-cloud-upload icon-large"> <span class="setting">&nbsp;Remote Upload<span></span></i><br><br>




      <label class="radio inline control-label"><input name="isp" value="nointernet" checked="checked" type="radio">



    <span>Upload Off</span></label>


      <label class="radio inline control-label"><input name="isp" value="vodafone" checked="checked" type="radio">



    <span>Upload On</span></label>




    <hr/>
      Changes will not take effect until the monitor is <span class="bold">rebooted</span>.
      <p class="offset0">
      <br/>
      <label for="submit" class="btn"><i class="icon-ok"></i> Submit Changes</label>
      <input id="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit Changes" type="submit" class="hidden" />

      <label for="reset" class="btn"><i class="icon-refresh"></i> Reset Form</label>
      <input id="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset Form" type="reset" class="hidden" />

      <label for="restore" class="btn"><i class="icon-home"></i> Restore Defaults</label>
      <input id="restore" name="Submit"  value="Restore Factory Defaults" type="submit" class="hidden" />
      </p>
      </form>


      <html>'''
    print htmlFormat.format(latitude=latitude, latHemi=latHemi, longitude=longitude,
    longHemi=longHemi, sensitivity=sensitivity,weight=weight)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? If this feels like a noob reinventing the wheel; i'm not. My boss wants this done with Python, and I have reached the stubborn point where if it can be done with Python then I want to do it with Python.

Thank you.

Comment: FWIW, not many people use old-fashioned CGI these days, they prefer to use Web frameworks like Flask, etc. But anyway, what you ask can probably be done fairly easily, but you're _much_ more likely to get assistance with this if you cut your code down to a [mcve] that focuses on your problem.

Comment: @PM2Ring thank you for the response. I can't use a framework as it is for a arm device with very little memory.

Comment: Fair enough. That info deserves to go into your question. FWIW, SO comments are just secondary information, like Post-It notes. We use them to help get questions (and answers) into a better shape. Important info shouldn't just be left in the comments.